# How do I access one of my models from within a ruby script in the /lib/ folder in my Rails 3 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried putting my script in a class that inherited from my model, like so:

```
class ScriptName < MyModel
```

But when I ran `rake my_script` at the command-line, I got this error:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant MyModel
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, should I name my file `my_script.rb` or `my_script.rake`?

Comment: what exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I have a ruby script that I want to run - on a cron job - that will do some task that takes 30 minutes. I know that I will eventually use a rake task to execute the script, and I will likely end up using `whenever` gem for the cron job and then use `delay_job` or `resque` or something like that to put the work in a background queue. But, for now...what I am trying to do is simply get access to my model from within this file (so I can both read from & write to my database). Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Just require the file. I do this in one of my rake tasks (which I name `my_script.rake`)

```
require "#{Rails.root.to_s}/app/models/my_model.rb"
```

Here's a full example

```
# lib/tasks/my_script.rake

require "#{Rails.root.to_s}/app/models/video.rb"

class Vid2 < Video
  def self.say_hello
    "Hello I am vid2"
  end
end

namespace :stuff do
  desc "hello"
  task :hello => :environment do
    puts "saying hello..."
    puts Vid2.say_hello
    puts "Finished!"
  end
end
```

But a better design is to have the rake task simply call a helper method. The benefits are that it's easier to scan the available rake tasks, easier to debug, and the code the rake task runs becomes very testable. You could add a `rake_helper_spec.rb` file for example.

```
# /lib/rake_helper.rb
class Vid2 < Video
  def self.say_hello
    "Hello I am vid2"
  end
end

# lib/tasks/myscript.rake
namespace :stuff do
  desc "hello"
  task :hello => :environment do
    Vid2.say_hello
  end
end
```

Comment: Since it is name `.rake` do I then need to re-write it to look like a 'normal' rake file? Or can I leave it as a 'normal' ruby file?

Comment: As shown in my example pure ruby is fine. This is a working example.

Comment: I think you have hit the nail on the head, the issue I am having is getting it working for my script. My script is a bit more complicated than this one, so tracing the failure is being a pain.

Comment: Btw, in this case...would `Video.create(:some_data => data)` work?

Comment: This is my script that I am trying to get working (along with the error logs) - https://gist.github.com/2860779 Any thoughts?

Comment: `Video.create(:some_data => data)` does work. The whole rails stack is available to you. I looked at your gist and that's not a good way to do it :) First try moving your requires at the top of the file just to see if it works. Actually, I'd move all that code out of the rake task and into a helper method. Just get that helper method to work. If it does, all you need to do is call it from your rake task.

Comment: Fair enough, well so I tried moving the requires to the top, and the message I am now getting is `no such file to load --nokogiri`. Should I just add Nokogiri to my gemfile and re-architect it that way, or should this hard require work?

Comment: Ok I simplified it drastically, and just have this - https://gist.github.com/2860779 (error attached). It seems that I can't get an AR connection with this `require`.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do to get this to work was put my requires above the task specification, and then just declare the `:environment` flag like so:

```
task :my_script => :environment do
 #some code here
end
```

Just by doing that, gave me access to all my models. I didn't need to `require 'active_record'` or even `require` my model.

Just specified environment and all my models were accessible.

I was also having a problem with Nokogiri, all I did was removed it from the top of my file as  a `require` and added it to my Gemfile.